# No registra datos de formulario SQL con Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013

Tengo una base de datos SQL server 2008 y VS 2013.

He probado a registrar información en una base de datos y funciona todo correctamente.

En un momento dado cambié de conexión a otra base en la misma `ip` y ahora ya no se registran datos.

¿Por qué puede ser?

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español, podrias agregar mas detalles a tu pregunta, como el codigo de que inserta, la cadena de conexión, o la estructura de tu tabla, ya que por el momento no podemos ayudarte mucho con la información que tenemos.

Comment: también podrías indicar si, por ejemplo, es posible contactar con la nueva base de datos... para descartar problemas a nivel de puertos y cosas así.

Comment: Buenvenida a StackOverflow. Tu pregunta es muy general y, en su estado actual, será cerrada en este sitio, ya que pueden ser mil cosas. ¿hay alguna excepción o mensaje de error? Si no lo hay, probablemente tu misma estas ignorando la excepción en tu código, así que sería bueno incluir un fragmento relevante (el del botón guardar, por ejemplo), además de indicar qué has intentado hasta ahora para diagnosticar y/o resolver el problema. ¿estas segura que puedes conectarte a la base de datos? ¿has intentado hacer alguna lectura de un dato y si lo recuperas?. Por favor edita tu pregunta para mejora

Comment: si bien es cierto lo que dice @jachguate , quizas se prodria espera un poco antes de intentar cerrar la pregunta y meterla en la pila para cerrar, pues el usuario es nuevo y solo hace una hora que se publico la pregunta y si el usuario añade informacion y esta se cierra no se podra responder si esta cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Si te conectas con el Sql Server Management Studio puedes ver esta db ?

Comment: Ademas podrias intentar crear un archivo .udl para probar la conexion, basicamente creas un archivo .txt y lo renombras a .udl, esto al ejecutarlo te mostrara un wizard para probar la conexion a la db

Comment: @AngelAngel, no he votado para cerrar esta pregunta, estoy con vos en el sentido de que se trata de un nuevo usuario y la pregunta recién se ha planteado, creo que hay que dar un compás de espera. Ya si el usuario no viene en un tiempo razonable (48 horas quizás), entonces, si votaría para cerrarla.

Comment: @jachguate quizas se entendio mal, nunca quise decir que usted votara para cerrar(pues no lo se, y de hacerlo esta en su derecho), solo recalque que estaba a favor de su comentario, y al verla en la pila comente lo anterior, espero se entienda. Saludos

Comment: No hay problema, @AngelAngel, de hecho, no dije que me acusara, o que me sintiera acusado. Sentí que no estaba de más la aclaración, sobre todo para los usuarios que se sientan tentados a terminar de cerrarla...

Comment: @jachguate Yo soy uno de los que votó para cerrar la pregunta. Considero que 48 horas es un tiempo exagerado para esperar a que la pregunta se edite si es que ha sido creada recién hace unas horas. El usuario debe entender que la respuesta no se va a respoinder sola sin más información. Lo importante de cerrar rápido la pregunta si es que no recibe atención del autor original es que se evite que se creen respuestas que posiblemente no ayuden a resolver el problema.

Comment: @Carlos, los usuarios nuevos, si vienen de foros, podrían esperar, por ejemplo, una notificación por correo, que en caso de SO no llega de manera inmediata (si es que se activa), y regresarán a visitar la pregunta luego de pasado un tiempo. Creo que 48 horas es un tiempo prudencial para que el usuario se vaya dando cuenta de cómo funciona el sitio.

Comment: soy nuevo y estoy esperando a que el moderador vea mi solicitud de cerrar esta pregunta

Answer (score 2):

Desde mi punto de vista:

- Es probable que los permisos asignados a la nueva base de datos sean diferentes de la anterior.
- Confirma que el usuario que tiene acceso a la nueva base de datos tenga credenciales de escritura.
- Verifica si las configuraciones de tu app siguen siendo las mismas, es decir, apuntan a la anterior base de datos?

Espero puedas solucionar pronto tu problema, éxitos en el desarrollo! Bendiciones!